# Lp space Inequality with L Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am currently studying $L^p$ spaces and am trying to prove the following inequality, which I just can't seem to work out:

Let $1 \leq p < r < \infty$. Then if $$f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}), \,\,\|f\|_r \leq (\|f\|_p)^\frac{p}{r}(\|f\|_\infty)^{1 - \frac{p}{r}}.$$

I have tried proving this via the generalized Hölder inequality to no avail, and I also tried just straight-out expanding everything out. Since $p < r < \infty$ and $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, we have that $f \in L^r(\mathbb{R})$ as well.
$$\|f\|_r = \left(\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|^r \, dx \right)^\frac{1}{r}, \,\, (\|f\|_p)^\frac{p}{r} = \left(\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|^p \, dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p} \cdot \frac{p}{r}} = \left( \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|^r \, dx\right)^\frac{1}{p}$$
Now this implies that $\|f\|_r \leq (\|f\|_p)^\frac{p}{r}$, so all I have to do is show that $(\|f\|_\infty)^{1 - \frac{p}{r}} \geq 1$, then this would be proven. But I am not sure where to go here. I tried using the infimum definition of $L^\infty$ without success, and I also tried using the fact that in this case we can write $\|f\|_\infty = \lim_{n \to \infty} \|f\|_n$, again with no success.

Am I approaching this the wrong way, or have I made a mistake? Any hints, corrections, or tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much simpler. $\int |f|^{r} =\int |f|^{p} |f|^{r-p} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}^{r-p} \int |f|^{p}$ Just rise both side to power $\frac 1 r$ to finish.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one question, on inequality, how do we know that we can pull the $r - p$ term out of the integral: because using Hölder's inequality there I got that $\int |f|^r = \int |f|^p |f|^{r - p} = \|f^p f^{r - p}\|_1 \leq \|f^p\|_1 \cdot \|f^{r - p}\|_\infty$. Do we know in general that $\|f^{r - p}\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty^{r - p}$?

Comment: Holder's inequality is not needed. $|f|^{r-p} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}^{r-p}$ almost eveywhere so $\int g|f|^{r-p} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}^{r-p} \int g$ for any non-negative measurable function $g$. @fluentsandfluxions

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense. Thank you so much for your concise answer and explanation!