# $L^p$ spaces 2-side inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am currently studying $L^p$ spaces. Let's consider probability space in the following. Also consider measurable $f$'s.

We know that (for example, [Proposition 1.4 here](https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf)) when $1\leq p< q$, we have $||f||_p \leq ||f||_q$.

Is there a known inequality for the reverse as well? That is, for $1\leq p< q$, can we get $$||f||_q \leq C ||f||_p$$ for some "nice" $C$? We can assume $f$ is bounded: $|f(x)|\leq B$.

[This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3887154/lp-space-inequality-with-l-infinity) provides $||f||_q^q \leq C ||f||_p^p$ with $C=B^{1 - (p/q)}$. This is close to what I am looking for, but can we get a version without the exponents just like in my request above?

Thanks in advance for all inputs!

Comment: You wrote "We know that when $1\leq p\leq q$, we have $||f||_p \leq ||f||_q$". It is not true. Consider $f =\chi_{[0,4]}$ (the characteristic function of $[0,4]$). Let $p=1$ and $q=2$. Then 
$$ 2= \|f\|_2< \|f\|_1=4 $$

Comment: @Ramiro hmm that inequality is fairly well known. E.g. see Prop 1.4 in https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf
Maybe the issue with this example is that $f$ isn't measurable?

Comment: $||f||_p \leq ||f||_q$ requires the measure space to be probability space. There is no hope for reverse inequality since  $||f||_q$ can be $\infty$ with $||f||_p<\infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes, I am considering a probability space. no hope? for bounded $f$, we do get $||f||_q^q \leq C ||f||_p^p$ as in description. I want to see if we can have a version without the exponents here.

Comment: You should edit the question mentioning that you are considering a probability space Quite often $L^{P}$ is used for $L^{p}(\mathbb R)$.  The constant will involve the bound on $f$, for sure.

Comment: In my example, $f$ is obviously measurable.  You had stated the inequality in the general case, where is false and counter-examples (like mine) are easy to produce.  Now, you have CHANGED the question: you added that the measure space is a probability space.

Comment: Proposition 1.4 in https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf is for FINITE measure space and it does NOT state that, "if $1\leq p< q$, then $||f||_p \leq ||f||_q$". There are factors multiplying $||f||_p$ and $||f||_q$. Those factor will reduce to $1$ in the case of probability spaces.

Comment: @Ramiro yes, thanks for pointing out the details. I've added the probability space assumption in my description.

Comment: Attention: The thread you mentioned (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3887154/lp-space-inequality-with-l-infinity)  provides $||f||_q^q \leq C ||f||_p^p$ with $C=B^{1 - (p/q)}$, where $B$ (and so $C$) may be $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a reverse inequality of the type $\| f\|_q\leq C\| f\|_p$, valid for all $f\in L^p$ with $p<q$ and $C$ independent of $f$ will fail. For example $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$, and $p<q=2$ on $L^p[0,1]$.

1. One case where such an inequality is true is when your underlying sigma algebra is finite, i.e. $L^p=\ell^p_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#%E2%84%93p_spaces) for the little $\ell$ notation, the subindex just means only the first $n$ entries are allowed to be nonzero). In this case $\| f\|_{\ell^q_n}\leq \| f\|_{\ell^p_n}\leq n^{1/p-1/q}\| f\|_{\ell^q_n}$ for any $p<q$.
2. If you restrict the inequality to hold, say for all $f\in X\subset L^p$ a linear subspace (and $C$ still independent of $f$ of course), things are a bit more interesting: If $L^p=L^p[0,1]$ and $(r_j)_j$ is the [Rademacher system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_system), $X=\text{Span}_{L^2}((r_j)_j)$, then [Khintchine's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality) says
   $$
   c_r\left( \sum_j |a_j|^2\right)^{1/2} \leq \lVert \sum_j a_jr_j\rVert_{L^r} \leq C_r\left( \sum_j|a_j|^2\right)^{1/2}.
   $$
   This means that on $X$ we have $\| f\|_{L^r}\sim \| f\|_{L^2}$ for any $r>0$. In fact, one way to interpret Khintchine's inequality is as saying there's a copy of $\ell^2$ (viewed as the $L^2[0,1]$ closure of the span of the $r_j$) embedded in $L^r[0,1]$.
3. In your example, where $X=X_B:=\{ f\in L^\infty: \|f\|_{L^\infty}\leq B\}$, you're treating a variant of the above type of problem (i.e. item 2), where $X$ is no longer a (linear) subspace. You saw that we can get $\| f\|_{L^q}\leq C_{B,p,q} \| f\|_{L^p}^a$, for some constant $0<a<1$. The constant $a$ can't be removed in general, as can be seen by considering $f_n(x)=x^n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you. On point 3, any thoughts on further assumptions on $f$ so that $a$ can be made $1$? Also, point 1 was the reason I was looking for reverse inequality in $L^p$ probability space!